# SetText NullPointerException for ArrayList in PopupWindow. Android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-popupwindow

I want to display an Array in a TextView for a Popup window. Only 1 item from the Array randomly. In this case I am using an ArrayList in my `MainActivity` and calling `randomArray()` to display. 
It does not work on the Screen_popup.xml. But it does work in the Main_activity.xml. I am using `TextView textView1` for the main_activity & `TextView txtViewArrayContent` for the popup window. I think the TextView is initialized correctly but has something to do with `setContentView`? Any pointers would be great, thank you!

The error in log cat is:

```
07-17 09:25:34.655  25779-25779/com.example.testarray_02 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.testarray_02, PID: 25779
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testarray_02/com.example.testarray_02.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Main Activity Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnClosePopup;
Button btnCreatePopup;
TextView newArray;
String item;

//***** Random Generator & ArrayList *****
final Random randomGenerator = new Random();
final ArrayList sample = new ArrayList() {{ add("Random Facts about Stuff"); add("Random Facts about Stuff 2"); add("Random Facts about Stuff 3"); add("Random Facts about Stuff 4");}};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Works - main activity layout
   // newArray = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // Does NOT work. ... popup layout
    newArray = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewArrayContent);

    randomArray();
    btnCreatePopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnCreatePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            customPopupWindow(v);
        }
    });
}

private void randomArray() {
    //setContentView(R.layout.screen_popup);
    item = (String) sample.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(sample.size()));
    newArray.setText(item);  // Error logcat points to this line
                             // Null Exception Error
}
private PopupWindow popupWin;
private void customPopupWindow(View v){
    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_popup,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        popupWin = new PopupWindow(layout, 600, 600, true);
        popupWin.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
        btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private View.OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popupWin.dismiss();
    }
};
}
```

Snippet of XML screen popupWindow

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewArrayContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
    android:text="" />
```

Comment: It doesn't exists/is not inflated before button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to initialize `newArray` by trying to find it by id in `activity_main.xml` file, but it's not there, so you get `NullPointerException`. To fix your code, remove `newArray` initialization and call of `randomArray()` from `onCreate()` method and add it in `customPopupWindwo(View v)` as follows:

```
private void customPopupWindow(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_popup,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
    newArray = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtViewArrayContent);
    //omitted rest for brevity
}
```